# using jquery to access event values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using for events for internet explorer we are currently using statements like this to access or change values:

```
window.event.cancelBubble = true;
clickX = window.event.screenX;
```

I was wondering how to do this cross browser or using JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a callback to a jquery binding function, it always take as first parameter a event that you should use, even on IE.

Don't use `window.event` if you're using jQuery.

Note that this is a jQuery wrapped event. For some uses you may need the `originalEvent` property of the event you get. Here's how you can get both in a callback :

```
​$('#A').click(function(e){
    console.log(e); // jquery event
    console.log(e.originalEvent); // native event
});​
```